# Flask-WTF form Validtaion failed

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

**Jinja Template Code**

```
<form method="POST">
  {{ form.name.label }} {{ form.name() }}
  {{ form.submit() }}
</form>
```

**Form Class**

```
class NameForm(FlaskForm):
  name = StringField('What is your name?', validators=[Required()])
  submit = SubmitField('Submit')

pdb> request.form
ImmutableMultiDict([('name', 'rohit'), ('submit', 'Submit')])
```

form.validate_on_submit() is returning False instead of True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fr the above to work you also need to add protection against cross-site referencing in the HTML code. Adding this line

```
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
```

might solve the problem.